# How to filter results simultaneously using Solr and Google Places API?

Tags: solr, google-places-api

I want to filter content using Apache Solr and then filter results using the Google places API or vice versa. Actually I want to use [this](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests) API from Google places.

So I want to filter both, Locations (using the Google Places API) with some features (using Apache Solr). Is that possible?If so how? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a wide open question so I'm not sure what languages, platform, etc. you are requiring. Also, have you started this yet? If so please post your code so that we can add on to it.

If no code, the only way I can think of answering this question is conceptually:

To call Solr and Google Places- you simply need to use an HTTP URL Request.

For Google Places this can be:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?Key&lat&long&radius
```

Where Key, Lat, Long, and Radius are just some of the parameters you can/should use.

For Solr this can be:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&wt=json
```

Where `*:*` means ask Solr for everything in json format. Clearly you would want to add parameters to this as well to call specific features, but the point is to answer question you can query both of these using HTTP URL Requests and then add the necessary arguments to the end of each URL.

Depending on the language you choose, the code calling these URL's will look different, but the effect will be the same.

It may also be a good idea to keep wt=json as a Solr parameter because the Google Places will also return its result in json format- so it may be easier and faster to work with json in both results.

I hope this helps. Please feel free to post comments or follow up questions if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I haven't started this yet,but investigating this.The language I am interested in is Php,and specific to Drupal.If you could explain the your above comments for php would be great.Thanks!

Comment: @sokratis- I'm a java guy so I use Servlets instead of PHP. However in PHP you can try something like this: $json = file_get_contents('http://somesite.com/getjson.php'); It should get you started! Good Luck!

Comment: @sokratis, additionally- you may try searching "php how to make http call json". There are a lot of relevant links to help get you started.